# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar por un valor en común en Bootstrap en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

estoy realizando un proyecto y a la hora de crearlo, no se como hacerlo para agruparlo. ¿Alguna idea?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explico un poco mejor lo que quiero hacer. Yo obtengo los datos en un array y estos mediante bootstrap los introduzco sin problema (data[0] en la fila 1, data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abFbP.png) en la fila2...).
Lo que quiero realizar es coger la primera columna que es la que me indica el tipo de movimiento y, que todas las que coincidan con lo que tiene escrito, se muestren en un submenú como en la primera imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando por interner pero no he encontrado nada sobre esto y no se si se podrá hacer.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor qué es lo que quieres conseguir? No entiendo tu pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: Lo acabo de explciar un poco mejor, lo que quiero es agrupar los resultados que tienen un campo en común y que, cuando le dé a ese agrupamiento, me salgan los datos de la derecha.